# How to get coordinates of end points in Cartesian coordinate system and the corresponding (rho,theta) in polar coordinate system of line segment

Tags: opencv, line, edge-detection

I have used Canny method to get edges of a image.Then I applied the approxPolyDP method to approximate edges,and got a set of polylines (not polygons) and line segments.Each polyline is formed from line segments.My purpose is to get coordinates of each line segment's end points in Cartesian coordinate system (2D plane) and the corresponding parameters (rho,theta) in polar coordinate.Any idea?Thanks!

BTW:I know that we can use the HoughLines method to find lines (not line segments) and get the parameters (rho,theta) in polar coordinate,or we can use the HoughLinesP method to find line segments and coordinates of end points.But the two method can not get the coordinates of end points of line segment and the corresponding  parameters (rho,theta) at the same time.

Comment: Maybe I got an idea:we can compute the (rho,theta) from two end points of a line segments.

Comment: This seems very straightforward unless you are unsure about the mathematics? In any case, this is SO so please post code (without all the transforms) - start with clearly defined input (including the format of the line segments) and then clearly define what you need as output. It will help you get help faster.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some sample C++ code for interpreting a line from OpenCV HoughLines. If you want the slope, just find two points and compute rise over run.

The important formula, which unfortunately is not as obvious as it should be in the documentation, is: `rho = x*cos(theta) + y*sin(theta)`

```
float yForHoughLine(float x, const Vec2f houghLine) {
    float rho = houghLine[0];
    float theta = houghLine[1];
    if (theta == 0)
       return NAN;
    return (rho - (x * cos(theta))) / sin(theta);
}

float xForHoughLine(float y, const Vec2f houghLine) {
    float rho = houghLine[0];
    float theta = houghLine[1];
    float cosTheta = cos(theta);
    if (cosTheta == 0)
        return NAN;
    return (rho - (y * sin(theta))) / cosTheta;
}
```

Here's the equivalent Python:

```
def y_for_line(x, r, theta):
    if theta == 0:
        return np.nan
    return (r - (x * np.cos(theta))) / np.sin(theta)


def x_for_line(y, r, theta):
    cos_theta = np.cos(theta)
    if cos_theta == 0:
        return np.nan
    return (r - (y * np.sin(theta))) / cos_theta
```